# Upgrading from excel to an actual database

Tags: database-design, csv, excel

Just started my first internship and I could use some guidance on approaching the project given to me. Simply put, all that needs to be done is to make a database and then transfer the data from a excel spreadsheet and then to automate daily data entry via FTP to the new database. I'm comfortable with SQL and basic database tasks but I'm unsure of the process to create a new database for a small company.

Unfortunately I don't have any DBA resources at said company and have no experience on how to manage a database at an organizational level. Considering that the DB will be taking in data automatically every day, I can't host it on my local machine but would rather host it with a cloud service or on-prem w/ remote access right?

How would you approach this task?

Comment: Unfortunately this is a pretty broad ask of a post for a site like this, but there are some specific things that we can guide you on. Couple questions: at what rate does the data change? At what rate does the database need to be updated? Is it just a single shared spreadsheet that's currently maintained? How is it shared (hopefully on a network share)? How big is the spreadsheet file and what do you forecast it's size to be in a year from now (if you had to guess)? I assume you want to use a free database system, or is a paid system a possibility?

Comment: I understand and appreciate any guidance. It is just a single spreadsheet that is currently maintained.  Data will be getting queried daily to be visualized so I would suppose it would only need to be updated daily.  The data coming in will mostly be numerical/financial reporting.

Comment: Sorry I might've updated my commented after you last reloaded the page. Please see the additional questions I added, and ideally you should update your post with the answers so others see the information as well.

Comment: If the data is numerical/financial in nature is it commercially sensitive? You need to consider how the data is protected but from input/output/at rest. What about backup strategies, archving etc

Answer (score 0):

This question is too broad and off-topic for this site. You are being asked to design and build a new application that improves an existing business process, which requires you to play at least three related, but different roles: that of an application architect (because you need to design a new software application), an infrastructure architect (because you need to lay out all the parts that will run, protect, and support that application, based on its design),  and the role of an application developer who implements the design.

Depending on your future career plans and your employer requirements, you have essentially two paths.

If you want to become an IT professional, [ask your employer to] buy a couple of introductory books on software and IT architecture. (I'm afraid I cannot recommend any at that level, as when I was in your shoes they didn't exist, but I recently read [this one](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/software-architecture-the/9781492086888/) and found it useful.) Read them cover to cover first, without doing anything material, then re-read the parts that [you will then realise] apply to your task, and then you'll know what to do next. Please come back here with any database-related questions.

If you just want to get the job done and move on, consider using one of the managed service providers, which has a product closest to what you need to achieve, such as [Zoho](https://www.zoho.com/), [ClickUp](https://www.zoho.com/), [Salesforce](https://www.salesforce.com/products/platform/overview/), or [Pega](https://www.pega.com/products/platform/pega-app-studio) (there are others that you can search for). (For the purposes of full disclosure, in no particular order, I simply heard of one of these, I visited the headquarters of another, yet another I use myself, and I do some consulting work for the remaining one.)